# When to use `session_maker` and when to use `Session` in sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, orm

[Sqlalchemy's documentation](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/session_basics.html#basics-of-using-a-session) says that one can create a session in two ways:

```py
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session
session = Session(engine)
```

or with a sessionmaker

```py
from sqlalchemy.orm import session_maker
Session = session_maker(engine)
session = Session()
```

Now in either case one needs a global object (either the engine, or the session_maker object). So I do not really see what the point of the session_maker is. Maybe I am misunderstanding something.

I could not find any advice when one should use one or the other. So the question is: In which situation would you want to use `Session(engine)` and in which situation would you prefer `session_maker`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [docs](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/session_basics.html#getting-a-session) describe the difference very well:

[Session](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/session_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.session.Session) is a regular Python class which can be directly instantiated. However, to standardize how sessions are configured and acquired, the [sessionmaker](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/session_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.session.sessionmaker) class is normally used to create a top level Session configuration which can then be used throughout an application without the need to repeat the configurational arguments.

Comment: but if you are in some module, you would have to import the sessionmaker object in order to create a session with it. At this point you might as well import the engine and create a session object with it. I do not quite see the benefit

Comment: I mean is the benefit really only the difference between `Session()` and `Session(engine)`?

Comment: It's not only the benefit of adding the `engine` object but a lot of other configuration options that you can add to the [session](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/session_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.Session). When you have an extensive configuration you notice the benefit of `sessionmaker`.